# Trying to run live matplotlib graph in Tkinter while using classes. Cannot resolve TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to get a live matplotlib graph working in Tkinter while using a class structure. I am using the code from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192133/embedding-matplotlib-live-plot-data-from-arduino-in-tkinter-canvas) which successfully runs a matplotlib graph in Tkinter(does not use class structure). Every time I try to run the code I altered I am given a

```
TypeError: __init__ takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I know this TypeError type question has been asked before. I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086384/python-typeerror-init-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-given) but the answer provided did not solve my problem.

The line of code that seems to be the problem is:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(Window().fig, Window().animate(), interval=1000, blit=Fals
```

I have tried altering how I call fig and animate but nothing seems to work.

---

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
xar = []
yar = []

class Window:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Tk.Frame(master)
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 4.5), dpi=100)

        self.ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(xar, yar)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.pack()
    def animate(self,i):
        yar.append(99-i)
        xar.append(i)
        self.line.set_data(xar, yar)
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, i+1)

root = Tk.Tk()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(Window().fig, Window().animate(),interval=1000, blit=False)
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, you are calling the WIndow() constructor - twice - and it takes one argument.  You aren't passing anything.

Comment: I also tried defining fig outside of the Window() class so I would only call the Window constructor once and it did not work.                                                                            
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, Window().animate,interval=1000, blit=False)

Comment: Leave `fig` where it is.  Just create the object once and then access its methods.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many mistakes:

As Paul Comelius said you have to create instance

```
app = Window(root)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(app.fig, app.animate, interval=1000, blit=False)
```

-

You have to use `self.fig` inside class to get it later as `app.fig`

-

`animation.FuncAnimation` expects callback - it means function name without `()`.
In you code it will be `app.animate`.

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(app.fig, app.animate, interval=1000, blit=False)
```

-

Full working code

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class Window:

    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Tk.Frame(master)

        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 4.5), dpi=100)

        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(xar, yar)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.pack()

    def animate(self,i):
        yar.append(99-i)
        xar.append(i)
        self.line.set_data(xar, yar)
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, i+1)

xar = []
yar = []

root = Tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(app.fig, app.animate, interval=1000, blit=False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this also possible without making the GUI lag every second? If you drag the window over the desktop it is lagging. I try something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you probably want something like this:

```
root = Tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(app.fig, app.animate(),interval=1000, blit=False)
root.mainloop()
```

This will not completely solve the problem as there is no argument for the `animate` function either.

Comment: I am trying to replicate this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192133/embedding-matplotlib-live-plot-data-from-arduino-in-tkinter-canvas )  only Id like to have it in a class type format.